# Temperature and Salinty from CMEMS netcdf file for specific geographical location

Tags: python, arrays, netcdf, netcdf4

I want to get the temperature `['thetao']` and salinity `['so']` of the sea surface (just the top layer) for specific geographical location.

I found guidance for how to do this on this [website](https://www.earthinversion.com/utilities/reading-NetCDF4-data-in-python/).

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np

fn = "\\...\...\Downloads\global-analysis-forecast-phy-001-024_1647367066622.nc"  # path to netcdf file

ds = nc.Dataset(fn)  # read as netcdf dataset

print(ds)
print(ds.variables.keys()) # get all variable names

temp = ds.variables['thetao']
sal = ds.variables['so']
lat,lon = ds.variables['latitude'], ds.variables['longitude']

# extract lat/lon values (in degrees) to numpy arrays
latvals = lat[:]; lonvals = lon[:]

# a function to find the index of the point closest pt
# (in squared distance) to give lat/lon value.
def getclosest_ij(lats,lons,latpt,lonpt):
  # find squared distance of every point on grid
  dist_sq = (lats-latpt)**2 + (lons-lonpt)**2
  # 1D index of minimum dist_sq element
  minindex_flattened = dist_sq.argmin()
  # Get 2D index for latvals and lonvals arrays from 1D index
  return np.unravel_index(minindex_flattened, lats.shape)

iy_min, ix_min = getclosest_ij(latvals, lonvals, 50., -140)
print(iy_min)
print(ix_min)


# Read values out of the netCDF file for temperature and salinity
print('%7.4f %s' % (temp[0,0,iy_min,ix_min], temp.units))
print('%7.4f %s' % (sal[0,0,iy_min,ix_min], sal.units))
```

Some details on the nc-file I am using:

```
dimensions(sizes): time(1), depth(1), latitude(2041), longitude(4320)
 variables(dimensions): float32 depth(depth), float32 latitude(latitude), int16 thetao(time, depth, latitude, longitude), float32 time(time), int16 so(time, depth, latitude, longitude), float32 longitude(longitude)
    groups:
dict_keys(['depth', 'latitude', 'thetao', 'time', 'so', 'longitude'])
```

I am getting this error:

```
dist_sq = (lats-latpt)**2 + (lons-lonpt)**2
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2041,) (4320,)
```

I suspect there is an issue with the shapes/arrays. In the example of the website (link above) the Lat and Lon have a (x,y), however this NC file only has for Latitude (2041,) and for Longitude (4320,).

How can I solve this?

Comment: See `xarray` library. Use `.sel()` with `method="nearest"`. Example here https://xarray-contrib.github.io/xarray-tutorial/oceanhackweek-2020/xarray-oceanhackweek20.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the lats and lons are vectors with different size...

I usually do this if using WGS84 or degrees as unit:

```
lonm,latm = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)
dmat = (np.cos(latm*np.pi/180.0)*(lonm-lonpt)*60.*1852)**2+((latm-latpt)*60.*1852)**2
```

Now you can find the closest point:

```
kkd = np.where(dmat==np.nanmin(dmat))
```

Comment: the  ``` lonm,latm = np.meshgrid(lons,lats) ``` solved my problem

Comment: I have your code working. However I got a question about the results that come back. I have a list of 4 lats and lons but it only can return variables in the netcdf for one of them. The others which are relative close return nothing and are being handeld as NAN. Any idea why this might be.?